# In Windows 8 when the fast startup mode is enabled, shutdown saves the windows services

Tags: windows, services, shutdown

In Windows 8 when the fast startup mode is enabled, shutdown saves the windows services and resumes the services when powered ON again. This behavior is different from normal shutdown as services dont get shutdown event and also service is not re-started when computer is powered ON again instead services resume from previous state.

Does anyone have some solution or work around for this?

Comment: This behaviour is probably by design, since restarting all those services would probably make the startup not-so-fast...